# Accessing a forms html programatically in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If I have a form called index.aspx and I want to set the background colour programatically how do I do such a thing? Like if I wanted to set the pages background by calling a method called Changebackground?

```
Sub ChangeBackground()
       ' change forms html here 
    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried searching for a suitable property to access on MSDN API. I figure there is some way to access the background property, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first make the "body" element a server control, assign it an ID, then set CSS style to the body element's "style" attribute, for example:

**ASPX** (Note that "body" element is now a server control):

```
<body runat="server" id="body">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**ASPX.CS:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     body.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:red";
}
```

This code will set the page background to red.

Comment: btw: The code was written in C#, you can easily turn it into VB.NET.